# out-of-order versus in-order execution in the context of code written in C\C++

Tags: c++, c, cpu-architecture

Could anyone explain to me(in plain english) out-of-order versus in-order execution? I'm reading some theoretical texts on that and I feel that I can't quite grasp it. A small example in the context of C\C++ could be of help. What are the particularities in regards to multicore processors and multithreading?

Comment: Out-of-Order execution is completely orthogonal to multicore processors and multithreading.

Comment: Out-of-Order execution doesn't have to do with C or C++.

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt my question actually does. I know it's a "technique" employed in designing microprocessor but in order to execute something on those microprocessors we need to write code and some of us write it in languages like C and C++. I was asking for a C\C++ example which would illustrate the "triggering" of out-of-order execution.

Comment: +1 I was expecting an example code that would cause issues due to out of order execution as well. The reason is we go through large code bases with memory fencing to tackle this but what in reality would happen if memory fencing was not used is what I'm trying to understand

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Out-of-order execution is a technique used by engineers who create microprocessors.  The result affects the way the microprocessor executes machine instructions, which we usually write using "assembly language."

It's important to realize that out-of-order execution is not something the programmer implements -- it is a mechanism on the microprocessor.  A programmer might write assembly code which makes clever use of a particular implementation, but the same code written on a later microprocessor might not benefit from that cleverness, as the processors' design as to what is executed out-of-order might differ.

With that preamble, here is an example of a potential out-of-order execution:

- Suppose we have a microprocessor which can execute two instructions at the same time.
- The instructions are accessing the same set of registers, so the ability to execute two instructions at the same time is neither multicore nor multithread.
- If an instruction changes a register, it cannot be executed at the same time as an instruction which reads or writes to that register -- because the intermediate result is not available and the register would receive a wrong result.
- Some example program contains the following x86 assembly instructions:

  ```
  1) mov eax, 0
  2) mov ebx, 1
  3) mov edx, 2
  4) inc edx
  5) mov ecx, 3
  ```

During the first time slot, instructions (1) and (2) execute together because (2) does not depend on the result of (1).

During the second time slot, the microprocessor determines that (3) and (4) cannot execute together -- (4) uses the value of `edx`, which will not be correctly set to `2` until instruction (3) completes.

The microprocessor can be built to handle this in a couple of ways:

1. The processor can "stall" or "pipeline stall" and execute only a single instruction (3), at this time slot.  Then instruction (4) will execute as part of the next time slot, probably simultaneous with (5).
2. The processor may "out-of-order" execute an instruction rather than (4).  In this example, instructions (3) and (5) may execute simultaneously, because (5) does not depend on the result of either (3) or (4), and (4) is not made incorrect by the execution of (5).  **Therefore, (5) may be executed out-of-order relative to (4).**

It is worth realizing that the firmware decisions about out-of-order execution are made by transistors and microcode inside the microprocessor.

Other worthy related topics include superscalar dispatch, speculative execution, and exception boosting or hoisting.

Answer (score 5):

A program consists of a series of instructions in memory. The processor reads the instructions in order and executes them. To the user, they appear to execute in order. However, the processor may speed execution by reordering them in time. This helps because some instructions are slower than others, and some fast instructions may not require the results of preceding slow instructions.

Here is a snippet of C. It doesn't really illustrate much because the compiler is allowed to reorder operations before they get to the CPU, but we can assume for the sake of argument that it doesn't.

```
int can_reorder() {
    int a = 4, b = 3;
    int c = a + b; // fast instruction
    int d = a / b; // slow instruction
    return c + a; // fast instruction may complete before division
}
```

Multithreading is totally orthogonal. (Almost) no instruction in thread A depends on the result of an instruction in  thread B, so the CPU is free to choose to execute whichever thread is more convenient in a given execution unit on a given cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we have a processor. It does a bytecycle. Lets call the incoming bytecycle instructions H E A F B D C G. The processor can do 2 instructions at once when they are not related. However it cannot know the total incoming of instructions. Instead it has window over how far ahead it can see incoming bytes and try to reorder them. This is a quality in out of order processors. You will se why.

Lets say our processor can see only 3 bytes ahead to reorder them. And the most optimal way would have been to have gone AB CD EF GH. Out of order proccessor (with window of 3) would have gone H EF AB DC G.

So if the proccessor would have had access to all it would have taken 4 cycles to do all the instructions. As it could reorder everything. With out of order (and a window of 3 bytes) it would take 5 cycles (H EF AB DC G). And if there was no out of order execution it would have been (H E A F B DC G) 7 cycles. (DC happened to come in right order - in the eyes of the processor).

And with no processor parallelism architecture. It would have done everything as it came H E A F B D C G (in 8 cycles). Without doing more than one instruction at a time

Out of order execution is an attempt to maximize paralell execution.

I learned alot from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLsdS0zQ82c

Also when it comes to mutlicoring - It dont seem to have anything to do with out of order execution. A one core processor can still execute more than one thing at once. And would therefore benefit from out of order architecture.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar_processor

And use:
Instruction-level parallelism